# Mapping on a surface

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces

How can I map a 2D flat picture on a curved surface whilst maintaining distances and angles between points of the flat picture as much as possible?

Comment: Something like these: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map_projection ?

Comment: @N74 Thank you, I will look into it.

Comment: Conformal maps will, in general, have _severe_ distortion of lengths and areas.

Comment: You want isometry between a curved surface that has non-zero Gauss curvature$K$ and a flat plane that has $K=0$ which so are not inter-mappable that way.If you step on an empty eggshell it will become flat but will be broken due to cracks that formrd everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

In general preserving all distances will not be possible at all, while [preserving angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map) is possible for some kinds of surfaces. The [uniformization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem) allows for some classification for the latter. Usually there is a balance between distortion of angles and distances: the more you preserve one, the more severely you will distort the other. So without further details on how to balence them against one another, it is impossible to come up with a formalization of what would make an optimal solution.

One exception would be [developable surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developable_surface) which thanks to their zero [Gaussian curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature) are already intrinsically flat. Those can be mapped to the plane with perfect preservation of angles and distances.

In the case of a sphere as curved surface, the topic has been intensely studied for the purpose of map-making. See Wikipedia articles for [map projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection) and [list of map projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections). The latter has distance-preserving maps listed as [*equidistant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Equidistant), angle-preserving maps as [*conformal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Conformal), area-preserving as [*equal-area*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Equal-area), and many characterized as [*compromise*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Compromise_projections) since they balance these goals in various ways. Note that while angle and area preservation are global properties, equidistant projections will only preserve *some* distances, e.g. those to a given point of reference ([azimuthal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuthal_equidistant_projection)).

Comment: "the more you preserve one, the more severely you will distort the other" How should we understand this? If a mapping preserves distance it also preserve angles.

Comment: @JohnMa: You are right, I was less precise than I should have been. Amended my answer.